# Add doctest.h to CMAKE project

Tags: doctest

I am struggling to add the doctest library to my project.

I have the following

```
\apps
  |____ \app1
  |        |____ App1.cpp, App1.h <<== which uses lib_a
  |        |____ CMakeLists.txt
  |                
  |____ \src
          |____ \lib_a
                   |____ \include : Class_a.h
                   |____ Class_a.cpp <<== which uses doctest
                   |____ CMakeLists.txt
  |____ \tests
          |____ \doctest
          |        |____ doctest.h <<== from the GitHub project
          |_____ CMakeLists.txt
```

The /test/CMakeLists.txt is

```
set(LIBDOCTEST_H
     "./doctest/doctest.h"
     )

add_library(lib_doctest INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(lib_doctest INTERFACE "doctest")

set_target_properties(lib_doctest PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

source_group(
  TREE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/doctest"
  PREFIX "Header Files"
  FILES ${LIBDOCTEST_H})
```

and \lib_a\CMakeLists.txt includes the additional lines below

```
target_link_libraries(lib_a PRIVATE lib_doctest)
target_compile_features(lib_a PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
```

This allows me calling `#include "doctest.h` in Class_a.cpp.
However, when I compile it, the program gives some linking errors

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol for
"int __cdecl doctest::detail::setTestSuite(struct doctest::detail::TestSuite const &)"
```

Any suggestion please?

**UPDATE**
I have managed to do it. For reference, I am adding the way I did it.

In test/CMakeLists.txt I have used

```
add_library(lib_doctest INTERFACE)
target_sources(lib_doctest INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/doctest.h)
target_include_directories(lib_doctest INTERFACE
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
)
```

In src/lib_a/CMakeLists.txt I have added the following lines (to be improved)

```
enable_testing()
add_executable(tester Class_a.cpp Class_a.h)
target_include_directories(tester PUBLIC "include")
target_link_libraries(tester PRIVATE lib_b lib_c lib_d) # I actually have other libraries to use here
target_link_libraries(tester PUBLIC lib_test)
set_target_properties(tester PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "TEST")
add_test(Tester tester)
```

Then if I want to add a test to my source file (e.g. Class_a.cpp) I do like this at the end of the file

```
#ifdef TEST
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
#include "doctest.h"

TEST_CASE("testing example") {
    CHECK(1 == 1);
}
#endif
```

In Visual Studio I can then select the tester.exe and run it to execute the test of the library

As usual, if you think I can do better please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

A more clean way of doing this is to create a Doctest.cmake module:

```
if(ENABLE_DOCTESTS)
    add_definitions(-DENABLE_DOCTEST_IN_LIBRARY)
    include(FetchContent)
    FetchContent_Declare(
        DocTest
        GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/onqtam/doctest"
        GIT_TAG "932a2ca50666138256dae56fbb16db3b1cae133a"
    )

    FetchContent_MakeAvailable(DocTest)
    include_directories(${DOCTEST_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

Then include it in your main CMakeLists.txt as an option to enable it or disable it.

```
option(ENABLE_DOCTESTS "Include tests in the library. Setting this to OFF will remove all doctest related code.
                    Tests in tests/*.cpp will still be enabled." ON)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
include(Doctest)
```

When linking your library that uses Doctest or your test framework main:

```
target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC doctest)
```

Comment: If you dont want to use FetchContent you can also use Doctest with conan packages and generate a cmake "integrator". then you can use find_package() to populate those library directories